# REGEX remove spaces or dashes, if they are in between numbers

Tags: bash, credit-card

I'm in the process of modifying an existing regex to match Credit Card numbers. Sometimes such numbers are presented as follows that separate the number chunks with spaces or dashes as follows;

```
3756-4564-2323-3435
3756 6432 3233 435
```

These types of matches should be preprocessed to remove those special characters. Usually the number chunks are of 3 to 4 digits.

thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)? This is very straightforward.

Comment: So, you would want to use Regex substitution then? Something simple like `(\d{4})[ -](\(\d{4})[ -](\d{4})[ -](\d{3,4})` for the match and `\1\2\3\4` for the replace should do the trick.

Comment: Im sorry Ed, Im not good at regex. Appreciate if you could help

Comment: thanks micsthepick. I have modified your suggestion to comply with BASH, ([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{3,4})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ed mentioned, you should try to solve things on your own before asking for the solution. Otherwise, shouldn't `(\d{4})[ -](\(\d{4})[ -](\d{4})[ -](\d{3,4})` match the number correctly, storing each part in capturing groups 1-4?

If you need to handle numbers that do not already have separators, just make them optional with the `?` qualifier: `(\d{4})[ -]?(\(\d{4})[ -]?(\d{4})[ -]?(\d{3,4})`.

Comment: Thanks @mic. My bad. i have used sed to replace `sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{3,4})/\1\2\3\4/g' *` but how use it to repalce all the matches within a file

Comment: @user3148655 "Have you tried" the global flag, `g`, `sed -i ‘s/([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{3,4})/\1\2\3\4/g’ file.txt` should work fine.

Comment: yes. it gives me this error. `sed: -e expression #1, char 67: invalid reference \4 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: @user3148655 `sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{3,4})/\1\2\3\4/g' a.txt` works fine for me.

Comment: it works. but it does not replace the text in the file, only displays.

Comment: so then use: `sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{4})[ -]([0-9]{3,4})/\1\2\3\4/g' a.txt > a.txt`, you need to use the basic BASH operator; `>` which should "redirect" the output to the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you could remove anything that is not numbers with:

```
$ var="3756-4564-2323-3435"
$ echo "${var//[^0-9]}"
3756456423233435
```